# Query database and unsaved changes for validation with Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, validation, entity-framework-6

I have a data layer using Entity Framework 6 **Database First**. One of my entities represents a time span - it has a start date and an end date.

```
public class Range
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add validation that ensures `Range`s never have overlapping dates. The application will be saving added, modified and deleted `Range`s all at once. So I was playing with overriding `ValidateEntity` in my `DbContext`. Here is what I ended up with and then realized I still have a problem:

```
protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
{
    var result = new DbEntityValidationResult(entityEntry, new List<DbValidationError>());
    if (entityEntry.Entity is Range && (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added || entityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified))
    {
        Range range = entityEntry.Entity as Range;

        if (Ranges.Local.Any(p => range.EndDate >= p.StartDate && range.StartDate <= p.EndDate) ||
            Ranges.Any(p => range.EndDate >= p.StartDate && range.StartDate <= p.EndDate))
        {
            result.ValidationErrors.Add(
                    new System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbValidationError("EndDate", "Cannot overlap another range.")); //Could be StartDate's fault but we just need save to fail
        }
    }

    if (result.ValidationErrors.Count > 0)
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    }
}
```

The problem is that `Ranges.Local` does not query the database, and `Ranges`, which queries the database, does not include the unsaved changes.

For example: If I have a `Range` starting 9/1 and ending 9/8 in the database, which I modified in memory to start 8/1 and end 8/8, and I have also added a new `Range` starting 9/6 ending 9/12, then `Ranges.Any(p => blockOut.EndDate >= p.StartDate && blockOut.StartDate <= p.EndDate)` will return `true` for the added `Range` because the currently saved `Range` overlaps. But it is actually valid because in memory, those dates have been changed and when it saves there will be no overlaps.

Is there any way to query the combination of Local and the database, i.e. only query the database for records that are not in Local?

EDIT:

Updated code that I think works in response to Steve Py's answer below:

```
//Check Local first because we may be able to invalidate without querying the DB
if (BlockOutPeriods.Local.Any(p => blockOut.ID != p.ID && blockOut.EndDate >= p.StartDate && blockOut.StartDate <= p.EndDate))
{
    result.ValidationErrors.Add(
            new System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbValidationError("EndDate",
            "Block out cannot overlap another block out."));
}
else 
{
    var editedIDs = BlockOutPeriods.Local.Select(p => p.ID);

    //!Contains avoids reading & mapping all records to Range model objects - better?
    if (BlockOutPeriods.Any(p => blockOut.EndDate >= p.StartDate && blockOut.StartDate <= p.EndDate && !editedIDs.Contains(p.ID)))
    {
        result.ValidationErrors.Add(
                new System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbValidationError("EndDate",
                "Block out cannot overlap another block out."));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Union` between the local state and data state, providing an `IEqualityComparer` to match the PKs so that local is used without duplicating from data set.

```
var result = Ranges.Local
    .Where(p => range.EndDate >= p.StartDate || range.StartDate <= p.EndDate)
    .Union(
        Ranges.Where(p => range.EndDate >= p.StartDate || range.StartDate <= p.EndDate),
        new RangeEqualityComparer())
    .Any(p => p.RangeId != range.RangeId && range.EndDate >= p.StartDate && range.StartDate <= p.EndDate);
```

This should:

- pull any ranges from `Local` which potentially span the desired start/end date.
- union with any ranges from DB which potentially span the desired date range.
- check for the existence of any other record (`<>` my ID) that covers the range.

Comment: Thanks, I think a union, or querying both is the answer. I just wanted to be sure there was no existing collection combining the two. A couple things: I don't think I can have the where clause on the local set because that fails for the case of a `Range` that was overlapping but was edited to no longer overlap. 2nd, I think if I query Local alone first, I can save some trips to the database when a `Range` is invalid - see my edit. Not sure if the `Contains/IN` it uses is better or worse than union. Last, Local seems to already include _all_ of my records, not just the edits for some reason.

Comment: Local will contain all records that were loaded into the context. So if the code had a misplaced `.ToList()` prior to filtering, this could be bringing across more entities than you expect. That or a long-lived DbContext. Both situations would be problematic as the system grows. It's good to track down potential issues like that early. One possible issue of trying to optimize out the DB call might be concurrent updates. I.e. someone else creates another range entry, though this would be a challenge if someone edits another range. (local differs from DB)

Comment: Good point. They are loaded from some logic on the parent object that has to access them to calculate one of its fields. I load the ones in range from the database and then sort of manually do a union on that set with the saved ones as well. I could've probably used an actual LINQ union, as you've suggested here but didn't think of that. Thanks for your help, Steve. I have a sort of related question here if you'd care to attempt to answer that one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192303/update-entity-framework-dbcontext-cache-navigation-collection-property-after-a

Comment: I do have a concurrecy datetime2 column in place, but in this application, I luckily don't need to worry about it much especially for these records.